# How to sum the values for bins with the same location?

Tags: qgis, data, layers

I have two maps in CSV form, each has a latitude, longitude, and value column. Since not all the positions in one map are in another map, is there any way in QGIS to display a new map which only shows the points that are in both of the original maps? Besides, is it possible to display the value of each bin in the new map as a function (e.g. sum) of the values of original maps?

Comment: csv form - is csv files added in qgis project? If yes, save csv1 and csv2 in shape-file (Right click - Save As...). Select menu Vector -> Spatial Query: Source - csv1shp, Reference - csv2shp, Where the feature - Equals. Save selected features in new shapefile or copy selected records (attributes) in Excel for new csv file.

Comment: BTW is their any 'Calculator' in QGIS that can allow us simply doing summations, etc. directly? I run the query and it is very slow for some reason and often 'not responding' so I have to restart QGIS many times...

Comment: Actually I tried many many times the spatial query and none is completed... Every time I try it, it makes QGIS 'Not responding'.... I checked the memory and CPU usage and everything was ok, any idea to resolve the 'Not responding' problem? Thanks

Comment: Finally I get it work, but I get another problem.. "The query from 'Map1' using 'FID' in field not possible"... Could anyone show me how to save the output file? Thanks again...

Comment: How many records in your csv files? When you done [Select menu Vector -> Spatial Query: Source - csv1shp, Reference - csv2shp, Where the feature - Equals] - in csv1shp selected features which equals with features of csv2shp layer. Then for output shapefile you should save selected features (Right click on csv1shp layer - Save SELECTED As...)

Comment: Thanks HasT I tried it and it works. I need to do some calculations with 3 or more maps, do I have to do that process again and again? Is there any simpler way which may lead to the same result? (e.g. MapInfo has a calculator to do calculations on overlapped maps) Thanks

Comment: 'with 3 or more' - maybe easy way is using PostgreSQL/PostGIS database (fast work with big data then desctop GIS, flexibility queries). How import in database csv file - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727245/import-csv-table-in-postgresql and some way how compare features - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66991/compare-features-in-postgis-with-updating-attributes. I added first comment in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Save csv1 and csv2 in shape-file (Right click - Save As...). Select menu Vector -> Spatial Query: Source - csv1shp, Reference - csv2shp, Where the feature - Equals. Save selected features in new shapefile or copy selected records (attributes) in Excel for new csv