# Spatial Query: The query from "LayerName" using "FID" in field not possible

Tags: qgis, spatial-query

In QGIS Wien, I am performing a spatial query with two layers (points and buffer areas) and receive the following error when creating a new layer with intersecting features: The query from "LayerName" using "FID" in field not possible.

Spatial query settings:
- where the feature: intersects
- and use the result to: create new selection

In the same file, I have performed the same spatial query with other layers (points and buffer areas) without running into this problem.

How should I go about fixing the error?

Comment: Have you a unique field in your layers? And what kind of layer are they? shape, postgres ecc..

Comment: Good questions. Yes, unique field (each column has a unique header). The layer is a shape file of hospital locations in the US (Data: http://geocommons.com/overlays/106078).

Comment: There is a similar issue in the comments here (with solution):  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67133/how-to-sum-the-values-for-bins-with-the-same-location

Comment: I don't know why it happens but it's improbable that it is a bug. What i can suggest is to verify topology of the layer (polygons most of all) or import the 2 layers in grass for a topology correction and then extract them as shape and do again the spatial query.

Answer (score 1):

1. Apply Spatial Query
2. If error message appears go to step 3
3. Close Spatial Query
4. Right click on original layer and "save as"
5. Check the "Save only selected features" box